# Aligning button and alert vertically in Bootstrap 4 + Vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

Using `bootstrap-vue` in my VueJS application I'd like to place a button and an alert next to each other in one row with both items aligned centered vertically. Although I used `<b-row align-v="center">` this doesn't seem to work.

As you can see in this [example on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-haslett-dbsuo), the buttons are aligned but the alert is not.

How can I align all the items?

Answer (score 1):

The `b-alert` works a bit other than the buttons, so you have to apply different CSS rules to achieve the same effect:

```
<b-container>
  <b-row align-v="center">
    <b-col cols="2">
      <b-button variant="primary">Button 1</b-button>
    </b-col>
    <b-col cols="2">
      <b-button variant="secondary">Button 2</b-button>
    </b-col>
    <b-col class="d-flex align-items-center">
      <b-alert class="mb-0 w-100" show>An alert...</b-alert>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
</b-container>
```

This will work.

- aligns the items in the last `b-col` with the [flex utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/#align-items)
- remove the bottom margin (`mb-0`), so the item has nothing in the way to be positioned
  – applies `width: 100%` (with `w-100` class), so the alert doesn't shrink because of the `d-flex` of the parent; instead of this class, you could use `flex-grow-1`, so the `v-alert` takes up the available space.